# mongodb - add column to one collection find based on value in another collection

Tags: mongodb, join, pymongo

I have a posts collection which stores posts related info and author information. This is a nested tree.
Then I have a postrating collection which stores which user has rated a particular post up or down.

When a request is made to get a nested tree for a particular post, I also need to return if the current user has voted, and if yes, up or down on each of the post being returned.

In SQL this would be something like "posts.*, postrating.vote from posts join postrating on postID and postrating.memberID=currentUser".

I know MongoDB does not support joins. What are my options with MongoDB?

1. use map reduce - performance for a simple query?
2. in the post document store the ratings - BSON size limit?
3. Get list of all required posts. Get list of all votes by current user. Loop on posts and if user has voted add that to output?

Is there any other way? Can this be done using aggregation?

NOTE: I started on MongoDB last week.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, the simplest way is probably to handle this with application-side logic and not to try this in a single query.  There are many ways to structure your data, but here's one possibility:

```
user_document = {
     name : "User1",
     postsIhaveLiked : [ "post1", "post2" ... ]
     }

post_document = {
     postID : "post1",
     content : "my awesome blog post"
     }
```

With this structure, you would first query for the user's user_document.  Then, for each post returned, you could check if the post's `postID` is in that user's "postsIhaveLiked" list.

The main idea with this is that you get your data in two steps, not one.  This is different from a join, but based on the same underlying idea of using one key (in this case, the `postID`) to relate two different pieces of data.

In general, try to avoid using map-reduce for performance reasons.  And for this simple use case, aggregation is not what you want.

Comment: I ended up implementing it in a similar fashion.